# Jordan Measure of $[1,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to look at a simple example of Jordan-measure. Is the closed set  $A=[1,2]$ Jordan measurable?

Let $I=[1,2]$. Then $A\subset I$. Let $P$ be partition of $I$, such that $P=\{1,2\}$. There is only one sub-interval for this $P$, that is $I_j = [1,2]$.  Now, the inner Jordan-sum $$J_i = \sum\mu(I_j)=0$$

since the terms of this sum are the measures of sub-intervals $I_j$, such that $I_j \subset Int(A)$ and $1$,$2$ are not interior points.  However, the outer Jordan-sum $$J_o = \sum\mu(I_j)=(2-1)=1.$$

Here, we are adding the measures of those sub-intervals such that $\overline A\cap I_j=A\cap I_j=A\cap A=A\neq\emptyset$. Our single sub-interval fits the description here. The condition for Jordan-measure is that $inf J_o=sup J_i $, and in this case we'd have $0\neq 1.$

But I think that every closed set in $R^n$ should be Jordan-measurable. Jordan-measurability shouldn't (?) depend on $P$. Is this a flawed conclusion?

Comment: Why is $J_i=0$? There are clearly sub intervals of $[1,2]$ with positive measure.

Comment: But isnt the inner Jordan-sum $J_i$, the sum of all those measures $\mu(I_j)$, such that the corresponding sub-interval $I_j$ is a subset of the interior of $A$? And we only have one sub-interval here, too?

Comment: The inner Jordan measure isn't a sum, but the supremum of sums of measures of sub intervals contained in $A$. There are plenty of sub intervals with positive measure for $[1,2]$, like $(1.25, 1.75)$. Hence the inner Jordan measure is clearly not $0$.

Comment: My arguments are based on this specific $P$, with this one specific sub-interval. Are you saying that I should consider every single partition and corresponding sub-interval when it comes to the Jordan-measure?

Comment: Yes, though I don't think one has to work with partitions. If you are familiar with Riemann integrable functions, then this should be familiar to you.